# avd permission denied Windows 7

Tags: android-emulator, android-virtual-device

When I try to open an AVD using AndroidStudio I keep getting the following error.

Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
Could not launch 'C:\Users\me\AppData\LocalAndoroid\sdk\tools/emulator-x86.exe': Permission denied

I'm still new to AndroidStudio so I'm not sure what could be causing this error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

[image: screen shot of error]

Comment: It's because of the Windows **UAC** control. Authorize the `C:\Users\me\AppData\LocalAndoroid\sdk\tools\emulator-x86.exe` file to be launched as Administrator (right click on the executable and check `Run as Administrator`).

Comment: Even with Run as Administrator checked I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I found that the emulator conflicted with internet security program installed in my PC, in my case the program name is Kaspersky. As soon as I disabled this program the emulator worked perfectly. Thanks and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem, and resolved it by disabling kaspersky internet security. Open kaspersky, go to settings -> protection -> switch it off 
I tried running the emulator again